# Can we run a piece of JavaScript on any page in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

Can we make a piece of JavaScript code run on load of any page in Dynamics CRM Online? Not just for records. But on any page in Dynamics CRM (like Settings, Views etc.)

I wanted to build a listener service that will remain till Dynamics CRM is logged out. I'll be using EventSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts can only be added to customizable forms, ribbons and custom HTML web resource files.

Comment: actually there is a supported way to add a piece of javascript nearly everywhere inside CRM, leveraging the ribbon

Comment: I know, it's a nice trick which would need a bit more explanation than a one-liner. ;-)